# {"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"} Parse.com Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to update certain column value of my class matching the objectId of the class , Here is my code below

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Address");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);

query.equalTo("objectId", "xxxx");
query.first({
  success: function(object) {    
   alert(JSON.stringify(object));
    object.set("address","kkkkkk");
    object.save();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Now in the success function i get the row data for the given objectId, But the object.set and object.save alone not working , please advice what is gone wrong here.

I get "{"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"}" error in the reponse.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you check that client do have the permission to update the Class?

Comment: @eth3lbert But i can able to update other Class Values , IS there permission for particular Class can be blocked ?

Comment: Oops sorry, you should check both class level permission and object level(ACL) permission. Every class and object have there own permission.

Comment: I'll just commit an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check both class level permission and object level(ACL) permission and make sure client have permission to update the object.

Also note that, All class and object have their own permission.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var acl = new Parse.ACL();
> acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
> acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
> acl.setWriteAccess(user.id, true);
> model.setACL(acl);
> ```

Is a problem with ACLs. With this you can solve it

Comment: Could you explain your answer a little?

Comment: please check.
whether the given user id is allowed to write this object.
https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.ACL.html#methods_setWriteAccess