# Parse: ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, parse-server

I have a cloud function running some code like this and I am able to get a response for my query which is a valid class instance, but when I try to update the instance with the set method, I get the error you see in the title.

```
async function addToDB(apiKey) {
    const query = new Parse.Query(MyClass);
    query.equalTo('apiKey', apiKey);
    const response = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });
    const myInstance = response[0];
    myInstance.set('total', 100);
    try {
        await myInstance.save({ useMasterKey: true });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('E', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add `console.log(myInstance)` below `const myInstance = response[0];` line and update the post with the results? I would like to have better insight on the contents. I found a similar issue due to `class level/object level permissions` on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248394/code101-errorobject-not-found-for-update-parse-com-javascript-sdk).

Comment: `ParseObjectSubclass { className: 'MyClass', _objCount: 0, id: 'GstyehLqIN' }`

Comment: I'm not sure where are you running this. At first I thought you were using Google Cloud Functions but after investigating I think you are running this in Parse-Server, could you confirm? Either way, I found this [question](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/37) that may be of help, a solution was found in there. As @RubénC pointed out with the post he sent, it's probably a ACL problem. Also, here's the guide for [Parse queries](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#queries).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the options parameter ( `{ useMasterKey : true}`) should be the second parameter passed to `save`

the first parameter to a save should be a `null`, i.e. :

`myInstance.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })`

in essence, you are not passing the masterkey option in to the save call - which is why you are getting the 101 error (in my experience, a 101 is almost always related to permissions issues!)

see more here http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.Object.html#save